# How do I listen and spawn multiple child process in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to execute the same java jar file as a child process in nodejs in a for loop, but how do I listen to multiple child output???

The test.jar file runs in an infinite loop and all it does is increment and print the number.

Below is my code, and it does spawn multiple child process in nodejs, but it only print the pid for the last child, and the content from other childs are all added to the last child.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
var state = "java -jar " + "c://test.jar "
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var child = exec(state);

    // Add the child process to the list for tracking
    p_list.push({process:child, content:""});

    // Listen for any response:
    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(child.pid, data);
        p_list[i].content += data;
    });

    // Listen for any errors:
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(child.pid, data);
        p_list[i].content += data;
    }); 

    // Listen if the process closed
    child.on('close', function(exit_code) {
        console.log('Closed before stop: Closing code: ', exit_code);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to close over `i` when dealing with async processes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i){
        var child = exec(state);

        // Add the child process to the list for tracking
        p_list.push({process:child, content:""});

        // Listen for any response:
        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

            console.log(child.pid, data);
            p_list[i].content += data;
        });

        // Listen for any errors:
        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(child.pid, data);
            p_list[i].content += data;
        }); 

        // Listen if the process closed
        child.on('close', function(exit_code) {
            console.log('Closed before stop: Closing code: ', exit_code);
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: Works great! But why? Can you elaborate a little further on this, or point to some reference where this mechanic is explained? thx!

Comment: It's because `i` is a variable that gets promoted to the scope of each closure. Each time the for loop iterates, the variable gets mutated. Async functions, by their nature, are run AFTER synchronous code completes. So your for loop would first run and trigger 10 function calls, and then exit. The event loop would then wait for the callbacks to the async functions to fire. When the callbacks finally fire, they will still be referencing `i` which at this point, would equal to 10. By creating an anonymous function with `i` as the parameter, you're effectively cloning it, hence it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out the [Cluster API](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) for Node.JS.  Basically it lets you have a master process that spins up workers, and then each of those workers is it's own process.  I think that's what you need here?

Comment: i need something thats works with java jar file, that starts a java process in nodejs as a child process and listen to the output for each one. I don't see how you can start a child process for java jar file in Cluster API though.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry, I thought you meant you needed a separate node child process which in turn would just run the jar file.